# How can I use Enum::GetName in unmanaged C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, unmanaged

I am using managed extensions in VS 2008

I want to print the name of an en enum value

This code used to be fine VS 2003

```
Enum::GetName(__typeof(COMMAND_CODES),__box(iTmp))
```

but now I get a comile error

here is my enum

```
typedef enum  { /* Command codes */
    UMPC_NULL = 0,
    } COMMAND_CODES
```

Any clues ?
;

Comment: can you paste the error please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use [rtti](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) [typeid](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/typeinfo/type_info/)() and use the name() field?

Edit: From comment:

```
 Enum::GetName(COMMAND_CODES::typeid,iTmp)
```

Comment: I was thinking about that, but it doesn't work for enum members AFAIK.

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Cpp/0100__Development/Usingtypeidenumdatatype.htm ... agrees with me.

Comment: Yes this works great

Enum::GetName(COMMAND_CODES::typeid,iTmp)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, that is not possible in plain C++ since it doesn't have [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_science)).

You can use macros in plain C++ to workaround it:

```
#define COMMAND_CODES \ 
    ENUM_OR_STRING(CODE1), \ 
    ENUM_OR_STRING(CODE1),

// Enum
#define ENUM_OR_STRING(x) x
enum CommandCodes
{
    COMMAND_CODES
};
#undef ENUM_OR_STRING

// Names
#define ENUM_OR_STRING(x) #x    
char *CommandCodeNames[] =
{
    COMMAND_CODES
}; 
#undef ENUM_OR_STRING
```

Now the name of enum member is as easy to get as `CommandCodeNames[(int)commandCode]`.

Comment: Cheers but I had this code working in VS2003 .net 1.1 I guess

Comment: Maybe the type can be passed in at compile time

Comment: There's a big difference between *managed* and *unmanaged* code. The later one doesn't have reflection, so there's no such thing as Enum::GetName.

Comment: If you were asking about the difference between C++/CLI and C++ w/ managed extensions in regard to the code you should have phrased your question that way.